# generating request/response json from swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger

Given a swagger json, I would want to generate its request/response.

For example taking the case of petstore http://petstore.swagger.io/#,I should be able to generate this for POST /pet in node.js

```
 {
      "id": 0,
      "category": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string"
      },
      "name": "doggie",
      "photoUrls": [
        "string"
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string"
        }
      ],
      "status": "available"
    }
```

Comment: wondering how the swagger ui is able to generate it on the fly when we want to try out an api.

Comment: It's really not clear what the question is that you have.  Can you please edit your post and provide more info?